# Convergence of products of sequences implies convergence of sequence itself

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence

In my thesis I encountered the following problem for which I could not find a solution in literature: I have a sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ in a Banach space $F$ which has the following property:
for *each* sequence $(\alpha_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ in $\ell_p$ we have that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \alpha_nx_n$ converges in $F$.
My question is: can I conclude that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty ||x_n||^q<\infty$, where $q$ satisfies the usual condition $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$?

I have no idea if the answer is yes or no as I can imagine both to be true, so I am really curious if any of you has an idea or encountered something like this before.
I'm grateful for your answers in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is negative. Take $F=l_p$, and $x_n=e_n$, where $\{e_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is the natural basis.

Comment: Thanks, that seems logical.:)